# Team Foundation Server - keeping development versions of files seperate from production

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We are using Team Foundation Server and have some files being developed that we want under version control. We don't want these files being accidentally pushed into production. We plan on deploying them but right now they would break the web application. What is the best (simplest) way to version these files while avoiding the chance of them being accidentally deployed?

Comment: What is your current deployment process for production that makes you afraid that it will accidentally occur?

Comment: Everything gets checked into the trunk. After it's been tested we shove it to prod using file copy. In this case something got pushed out that wasn't ready. We are a team of three developers.

Comment: That sounds like more of a process problem.  If things are supposed to be tested before being deployed, and that didn't happen, then the process failed you not the tooling.  Make sure that those with privileges to push to Prod know the process that needs to be followed, and ensure that the Testing has been successfully completed before deploying.

Comment: We were looking into using branches but it seems complicated. Also looking into shelving and/or using tags.

Comment: We don't want anything in the trunk that will break the build. The trunk should always be deployable. We just don't know the best way to do this because we also want code under development versioned.

Comment: If you want to maintain multiple active versions of the code, then branching is the answer.  Not really any other options.

Answer (score 1):

Limit who has privileges to deploy to production.

Putting files in TFS for version control won't deploy them to production.  Only somebody with permissions in your production environment can deploy to prod.

What it sounds like you're saying is you have one version of code that you want to push to production, and another copy of the code with changes that you don't want to push to production yet (if you only had one version of the code, then you simply don't deploy until ready and problem solved)

If that is the case, then what you need is branches.  You have a branch for each separate version of the codebase that you are working on concurrently.  This can get complicated, because you have many options for how to structure your branching strategy, that can have significant implications on your development workflow.  See the [TFS Rangers Branching Guidance](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/) for more info.

The simplest branching structure if you only have the two versions of your codebase, would be a trunk/MAIN branch, then a DEV branch off of that.  Trunk/MAIN is what you push to production, DEV is where you do your development work.  And only merge into MAIN when you are ready to publish the changes to production.

Comment: That's exactly what happened to cause me to raise the question :)

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to shelve the changes. However, next best way (I would recommend) is to do the following:

1. Create STG Branch (This branch is where you would keep the
   production ready code or "in testing" code.)
2. Merge current code
   base to the STG branch.
3. Create PROD Branch (This branch is used
   to your currently in production code. (Easy to pull what is in
   production.
4. Merge STG branch with PROD when you are ready to push
   to production.

Keep the base code branch as your "trunk" branch and that is where the code gets kept that is 100% development and never gets into production by accident. (Check in early and often.)

Comment: +1 vote for the branching approach. for furthe information check out this guide: http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/